# count documents in mongodb grouped by a specific field

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Example data:

```
{ "category" : "abc" }
{ "category" : "abc", "ready": true }
{ "category" : "xyz" }
{ "category" : "foo", "ready": true }
{ "category" : "foo", "ready": true }
{ "category" : "foo" }
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "abc": {
        "count": 2,
        "ready": 1
    },
    "xyz": {
        "count": 1,
        "ready": 0
    },
    "foo": {
        "count": 3,
        "ready": 2
    }
}
```

Additionally it would be nice if I could optional give a from to date to make those kind of statistics by day or month.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you specifically want to use map-reduce?

Comment: nope - whatever works

Comment: do you need it exactly in that format or does this work for you `{ "_id" : "foo", "count" : 3, "ready" : 2 }`

Comment: nah don't need the exact format ;) - thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
db.foo.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$category",
        count: { $sum: 1},
        ready: { 
            $sum: {
                $cond: {
                    if: "$ready",
                    then: 1,
                    else: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Returns:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "foo",
    "count" : 3,
    "ready" : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "xyz",
    "count" : 1,
    "ready" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "abc",
    "count" : 2,
    "ready" : 1
}
```

Comment: awesome! any recommendation how to get a query in there? ts > date and ts < date ? can I just add a $query?

Comment: Aye, you just need to add a match stage before the group.